# Problem while updating the div tag

Tags: html

i have 2 pages, Login page and Contents page

--Login.php
I have a div with a message `'hi'`

--Contents.php
I have a logout button, clicking on which calls a javascript `function logout()`

--Javascript function

```
function logout(){
window.location='logout.php';
}
```

--logout.php

```
header('Location:Login.php');
exit;
```

After clicking on logout button in Contents.php page it switches successfully to Login.php page but i am not able to update the div in Login.php page

Comment: We need more info on how you're trying to update the div currently

Comment: i am not able to update the div currently. In the javascript function i.e. after window.location='logout.php' i am using document.getElementById('messageid').innerHTML='new message';

Comment: are you trying to update the login.php page from a script in the contents.php page? once you've done that first redirect,  to the logout.php page, everything else is pretty much ignored

Comment: When i logout , i am switching to the login page and i am not able to update the div in the login page using document.getElementById. Is there any way by which i can do it?

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript runs on the page it appears on.

When you send the browser to another page (e.g. by setting `location`), you are going to a new page and any scripts running on the current page stop.

Comment: It isn't clear what "it" actually is. Presumably you can know whatever condition it is on the server and do the work there.

Comment: When i logout , i am switching to the login page and i am not able to update the div in the login page using document.getElementById. Is there any way by which i can do it?

Comment: not from the script in the contents.php page, in any case. @Quentin is right. I'm not sure we can help without getting more details about your setup

Comment: Not from the page you were on. You need to step back and solve the problem instead of trying to get a particular technical implementation to work. You haven't said what that problem is though.

Answer (score 0):

what if you did this:

on your logout.php page:

```
header('Location:Login.php?logout=true');
exit;
```

then on your login page:
(using [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-querystring-values-in-javascript))

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (getParameterByName("logout") == "true") {
        document.getElementById("messageid").innerHTML = "Your message";
    }

    function getParameterByName( name )
    {
      name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
      var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
      var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
      var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
      if( results == null )
        return "";
      else
        return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }

</script>
```